# .fbx file with animations in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, assimp

I have an .fbx file which is having animations.

I tried using AssimpKit to import .fbx file but could not import the file I have added the file in project it self.

I used following code:

```
 let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Gag01_08", ofType: "fbx")
        let animFile = SCNAssimpScene(named: "Gag01_08", inDirectory: filePath, options: nil)
```

How to import fbx file for ARKit?
Can the animations will auto play?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the project-space of AssimpKit. It does not support the Assimp-release 4.1, which brings a more stable fbx-support with it.

To work around this issue you can try to upgrade the AssimpKit on your own or use assimp 4.1 as the native wrapper: without AssimpKit in it.